# How does one multiply and enhance items from one array with data from another array without the creation of duplicates?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, lookup, reduce

I have an array of catalogs where `catId` could be repeated.

Each catalog has a unique `segmentId`

```
const catalogs = [
  { catID: 3, segmentId: '3', segmentName: 'S3' },
  { catID: 2, segmentId: '2', segmentName: 'S2' },
  { catID: 2, segmentId: '3', segmentName: 'S3' },
  { catID: 1, segmentId: '1', segmentName: 'S1' },
  { catID: 1, segmentId: '2', segmentName: 'S2' },
  { catID: 1, segmentId: '3', segmentName: 'S3' }
];
```

Means against each `catId` there could be multiple segmentIds but segmentIds can not be duplicated for that specific `catId`

Now I want to assign an array of segments to the main catalogs array:

e.g here is an example array of segments that I need to assign:

```
[{id: '3', name: 'S3'},{id: '4', name: 'S4'},{id: '5', name: 'S5'}]
```

I am expecting this response:

```
[
  { catID: 3, segmentId: '3', label: { segmentIDName: '3_S3' } },
  { catID: 3, segmentId: '4', label: { segmentIDName: '4_S4' } },
  { catID: 3, segmentId: '5', label: { segmentIDName: '5_S5' } },
  { catID: 2, segmentId: '2', label: { segmentIDName: '2_S2' } },
  { catID: 2, segmentId: '3', label: { segmentIDName: '3_S3' } },
  { catID: 2, segmentId: '4', label: { segmentIDName: '4_S4' } },
  { catID: 2, segmentId: '5', label: { segmentIDName: '5_S5' } },
  { catID: 1, segmentId: '1', label: { segmentIDName: '1_S1' } },
  { catID: 1, segmentId: '2', label: { segmentIDName: '2_S2' } },
  { catID: 1, segmentId: '3', label: { segmentIDName: '3_S3' } },
  { catID: 1, segmentId: '4', label: { segmentIDName: '4_S4' } },
  { catID: 1, segmentId: '5', label: { segmentIDName: '5_S5' } }
]
```

I also tried to solve this myself, I am very close but not getting the expecting result:

```js
const catalogs = [
  { catID: 2, segmentId: '2', segmentName: 'S2' },
  { catID: 1, segmentId: '1', segmentName: 'S1' },
  { catID: 1, segmentId: '2', segmentName: 'S2' }
];

function addSegmentsToCatalogs(segments){

    let catalogUid = catalogs[0].catID;
    const lastCatalog = catalogs.slice(-1).pop();
    const insertionArray = [];
    
  catalogs.forEach(async (catalog) => {
    if (catalogUid != catalog.catID) {
      segments.forEach((segment) => {
        insertionArray.push({
          catalogId: catalogUid,
          segmentId: segment.id,
          segmentName: segment.name,
        });
      });

      catalogUid = catalog.catID;
    }

    if (!segments.some((segment) => segment.id === catalog.segmentId)) {

      segments.push({ id: catalog.segmentId, name: catalog.segmentName });

      if (
        catalog.catID == lastCatalog.catID &&
        catalog.segmentId == lastCatalog.segmentId
      ) {
        segments.forEach((segment) => {
          insertionArray.push({
            catalogId: catalogUid,
            segmentId: segment.id,
            segmentName: segment.name,
          });
        });
      }
    }
    });
  
  console.log(insertionArray);
  return insertionArray;
}

addSegmentsToCatalogs([{id: '3', name: 'S3'}])
```

Can anyone help me find the issue or suggest me better approach to solve this?

Comment: Having come up with new requirements to the expected result, how important is the order of the newly created items of the result array and in case precedence matters what would be the sort logic?

Comment: order is not important at all

Comment: After having alerted the other participants, I start questioning myself and want to countercheck on the expected result for the OP's provided `catalogs`-array in combination with not just a single-item `segments`-array of `[{id: '3', name: 'S3'}]` but of `[{ id: '3', name: 'S3' }, { id: '2', name: 'S3' }, { id: '1', name: 'S3' }]`.

Comment: @op, please add some more data and wanted result.

Comment: Please in the future, especially if there are several reasonable answers, if you choose to add or change the requirements, ask a separate question.  For this case, I would suggest simply doing two different steps, first the addition of the other objects, as originally asked, then the field merging into bits like `label: { segmentIDName: '2_S2' }` in a separate bit of code.

Comment: @StormTrooper ... Looking into all the answers / approaches and especially the comments the OP too might need to confess that from the provided test-case (the single-item `segments`-arrray ... really?) and description it does not seem to be clear at all how one should always assure the creation of every possible and valid new `catalogs`-item in terms of an item's `catID` and `segmentId`, even more in the context of already existing `catalogs`-items of the source data-format. Please OP do the effort of updating the source data (especially a test-worthy `segments` array) and the expected result.

Comment: i add more use cases, please check the updated question. I expanded the use case

Comment: 1/2 ... Summing it up. From all until now 3 solutions which do meet the OP's acceptance criteria the worst possible approach and implementation in terms of expressive, readable/maintainable, efficient and resource aware code has been accepted. Already the following line ... `segments = segments.filter(({ id }) => ![...new Set(catIDArr.map(obj => obj.segmentId))].includes(id))
` ... should disqualify the answer for being considered to get accepted.

Comment: 2/2 ... I'm sure neither the owner of this line nor the OP could tell within just few precise words what this line really does (not the goal of the line, which is clear) and why one does need this bazooka for assuring a unique array. Seeing this line or at the moment having come up with it, one should (have) immediately ask(ed) oneself what went wrong before, that one now is in need of such a monster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my understading, you are trying to create/push objects into a `catalogs` array based on the passed array of `segments` and `segmentID` will be unique for each `catID`. If Yes, here are the steps to achieve this requirement **:**

- Iterate over the `catalogs` array by using [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to concatenate the `segementId` in the `segmentName` and return the `catID`. i.e. `catIDArr`
- Now, get the unique catId's from the `catIDArr` with the help of [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) method. i.e. `uniqueCatIDs`
- Finally, Iterate over the `segments` array along with the `uniqueCatIDs` array to push the new objects into `catalogs` array.

Live Demo **:**

```js
// Input catalog array
const catalogs = [
  { catID: 3, segmentId: '3', segmentName: 'S3' },
  { catID: 2, segmentId: '2', segmentName: 'S2' },
  { catID: 2, segmentId: '3', segmentName: 'S3' },
  { catID: 1, segmentId: '1', segmentName: 'S1' },
  { catID: 1, segmentId: '2', segmentName: 'S2' },
  { catID: 1, segmentId: '3', segmentName: 'S3' }
];

// segment array
let segments = [{id: '3', name: 'S3'},{id: '4', name: 'S4'},{id: '5', name: 'S5'}];

// Creating a new array based on the catalogs array as per the required updated property.
const catIDArr = catalogs.map(catalogObj => {
  catalogObj.label = {
    segmentIDName: `${catalogObj.segmentId}_${catalogObj.segmentName}`
  }
  delete catalogObj.segmentName;
  return catalogObj;
});

// Getting unique category ID which will use for the iteration and building the objects.
const uniqueCatIDs = [...new Set(catIDArr.map(obj => obj.catID))];

// Filtering out the duplicate segements from the segment array to get rid from the duplicate enteries.
segments = segments.filter(({ id }) => ![...new Set(catIDArr.map(obj => obj.segmentId))].includes(id))

// Pushing the new objects based on the segment array.
segments.forEach(obj => {
  uniqueCatIDs.forEach(id => {
    catIDArr.push({
      catID: id,
      segmentId: obj.id,
      label: {
        segmentName: `${obj.id}_${obj.name}`
      }
    })
  })
});

// output
console.log(catIDArr);
```

Comment: 1/2... **First**, the above implementation does not meet the data-format of the expected result (though the answer was provided after the OP changed the requirements). **Second**, even with the correct/matching data-format the implementation is not reliable but error prone since the uniqueness of `catalogs` items does not get checked by both of an item's properties `catID` and `segmentId`. Thus the code works exactly for the OP's minimum provided use/test case but does immediately fail for an `segments` array of e.g. `[{ id: '3', name: 'S3' }, { id: '2', name: 'S3' }, { id: '1', name: 'S3' }]`

Comment: 2/2... **Third**, the algorithm for computing `uniqueCatIDs` is not well chosen for large arrays. **Last**, I do not understand any voting (here voting up once) on answers that seemingly have not been thoroughly tested by the voting person.

Comment: @PeterSeliger As per your **Third** comment, Can you please help me in understanding why `algorithm for computing uniqueCatIDs` will not work for large arrays ? Is there any drawback of using `Array.filter` method ? We can also do that by using `[...new Set(catIDArr)]` but that is not a good practice for large arrays.

Comment: @PeterSeliger As per your **First** comment, Why output is not meet the expected result ? As per OP, For each `catId` there could be multiple `segmentIds` and `segmentIds` can not be duplicated for that specific `catId` and my solution is fullfill this requirement.

Comment: @PeterSeliger As per your **Second** comment, How can you say that segments array can have objects with duplicate names ? This is not a use case.

Comment: `catIDArr.filter((item,index) => catIDArr.indexOf(item) === index);` ... It's not the `filter`, it is the nested `indexOf` which for each `filter` step introduces an additional iteration. Thus, even though `indexOf` exits early, the costs might grow close to quadratic in comparison to a lookup based approach.

Comment: @PeterSeliger Thanks for pointing that out. Understood the drawback of it . What about removing duplicates using `Set` ? Or which approach you prefer ?

Comment: _"How can you say that segments array can have objects with duplicate names ? This is not a use case."_ ... It certainly is the most important part of any use case scenario. It is even described by the OP ... _"Means against each `catId` there could be multiple `segmentId`s but `segmentId`s can not be duplicated for that specific `catId`"_ ... The OP later just did choose a poor test case by providing the single-item `segments`-array of `[{id: '3', name: 'S3'}]`.

Comment: _"Why output is not meet the expected result ?"_ ... Because the current implementation of yours creates/mutates catalog-items of the form `{ catID: 2, segmentId: '3', segmentName: '3_S3' }` whereas the OP prefers the data-structure of `{ catID: 2, segmentId: '3', label: { segmentIDName: '3_S3'  }}`. The OP came up with the latter requirement almost 43 hours prior to your answer.

Comment: _"Or which approach you prefer ?"_ ... It's not about my personal preferences, it should always be just about expressive, readable/maintainable, efficient and resource aware code. Finding the right balance in everyones eyes is the challenging part.

Comment: @PeterSeliger - Thanks for pointing these bugs out. I just updated the code snippet. Hope it will work as per the author expectation.

Comment: The currently updated code still will fail for following `segments`-array ... `[{ id: '3', name: 'S3' }, { id: '2', name: 'S3' }, { id: '1', name: 'S3' }]`.

Comment: @PeterSeliger I have updated the code snippet and it covers this scenario. `[{ id: '3', name: 'S3' }, { id: '2', name: 'S3' }, { id: '1', name: 'S3' }]`

Comment: _"I have updated the code snippet and it covers this scenario"_ ... the code snippet indeed does test against the scenario but the implementation produces the wrong result. One does **expect an array of 6 new `catalogs` items**. The OP's logging shows **just 5 items**. One does expect an `catalogs`-array with no item duplicates according to the OP's requirements. The OP's logging shows no duplicates but misses the following to be created item ... `{ catID: 2, segmentId: '1', label: { segmentIDName: '1_S3' } }`.

Comment: @PeterSeliger the segments array which you are talking about is not a valid scenario. Can you please tell me what will the final output based on this segment array `[{ id: '3', name: 'S3' }, { id: '2', name: 'S3' }, { id: '1', name: 'S3' }]` ?

Comment: _"Can you please tell me what will the final output based on this segment array"_ ... One just has to run whatever the `segments` array is supposed to be against my implementation which assures uniqueness by a key combination of an item's `catID`- and `segmentId`-value (again everything according to the OP's requirements; the OP is very explicit about this one).

Comment: Please have a look at my question edits, i just expanded my use case in order to get more clarification

Comment: @StormTrooper I have updated the code snippet and unit tested as per the use case you updated in the post. I hope it will work as per your expectation now.

Comment: @RohìtJíndal ... By doing ... `const catIDArr = catalogs.map(catalogObj => { catalogObj.label = { /* */}; delete catalogObj.segmentName; return catalogObj; });` ... the OP does not only create an array of new items but also does mutate each item within the original `catalogs` array, and of cause both arrays hold references of each of their items.

Comment: @RohìtJíndal ... Having probably solved the problem of preventing item duplicates with the last edit, the author did not update the explanation of how one assures such uniqueness and especially the literal meaning of this newly added but most essential line of code ... `segments = segments.filter(({ id }) => ![...new Set(catIDArr.map(obj => obj.segmentId))].includes(id))` ... nobody should be responsible in future of maintaining this one-liner.

Answer (score 2):

Some thoughts:

By having a data structure of elements who needs grouping and another data set which need a cartesian product without changing the given data, this tasks can be solved by at least two approaches with their advantages and disadvantages:

- Take some Maps
- Take an Object

---

### Take some Maps

At first, you could take nested [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)s and group by `catID` and `segmentId`.

The outer `map` looks like this:

```text
2:
    '2': { catID: 2, segmentId: '2', label: { segmentIDName: "2_S2" } }
1:
    '1': { catID: 1, segmentId: '1', label: { segmentIDName: '1_S1' } }
    '2': { catID: 1, segmentId: '2', label: { segmentIDName: '2_S2' } }
```

After that, iterate the key of the outer map and `segements` and get the cartesian product by keeping given data set.

At the end take the values of all inner maps as flat array.

Advantage:

- Clean approach,
- easy implementation,
- result in order of given data.

Disadvantage:

- Need to iterate the maps and transforming the data.

```js
const
    getObject = (catID, segmentId, segmentName) => ({ catID, segmentId, label: { segmentIDName: `${segmentId}_${segmentName}` } }),
    add = (catalogs, segments) => {
        const
            map = catalogs.reduce((m, { catID, segmentId, segmentName }) =>  m.set(
                catID,
                (m.get(catID) || new Map).set(segmentId, getObject(catID, segmentId, segmentName))
            ), new Map);

        segments.forEach(({ id: segmentId, name: segmentName }) => 
            map.forEach((mm, catID) => {
                if (mm.has(segmentId)) return; // prevent overwriting existing objects
                mm.set(segmentId, getObject(catID, segmentId, segmentName));
            })
        );

        return Array
            .from(map.values(), m => Array.from(m.values()))
            .flat();
    },
    catalogs = [{ catID: 3, segmentId: '3', segmentName: 'S3' }, { catID: 2, segmentId: '2', segmentName: 'S2' }, { catID: 2, segmentId: '3', segmentName: 'S3' }, { catID: 1, segmentId: '1', segmentName: 'S1' }, { catID: 1, segmentId: '2', segmentName: 'S2' }, { catID: 1, segmentId: '3', segmentName: 'S3' }],
    segments = [{ id: '3', name: 'S3' }, { id: '4', name: 'S4' }, { id: '5', name: 'S5' }],
    result = add(catalogs, segments);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

### Take an Object

This approach follows the idea of a direct result being updated while iteration is going on.

Advantage:

- No `Map`, no `Array.from`.
- Result is directly available.

Disadvantage:

- Needs beside of object for keeping track of seen groups of `catID`/`segmentId`, arrays for `catID` (type save) and result.
- Result not in order of `catID`.

```js
const
    add = (catalogs, segments) => {
        const
            references = {},
            catIDs = [],
            result = [];

        for (const { catID, segmentId, segmentName } of catalogs) {
            if (!references[catID]) {
                references[catID] = {};
                catIDs.push(catID);
            }
            references[catID][segmentId] = true;
            result.push({ catID, segmentId, label: { segmentIDName: `${segmentId}_${segmentName}` } });
        }
        
        for (const catID of catIDs) {
            for (const { id: segmentId, name: segmentName } of segments) {
                if (references[catID][segmentId]) continue;
                result.push({ catID, segmentId, label: { segmentIDName: `${segmentId}_${segmentName}` } });
            }
        }
        
        return result;
    },
    catalogs = [{ catID: 3, segmentId: '3', segmentName: 'S3' }, { catID: 2, segmentId: '2', segmentName: 'S2' }, { catID: 2, segmentId: '3', segmentName: 'S3' }, { catID: 1, segmentId: '1', segmentName: 'S1' }, { catID: 1, segmentId: '2', segmentName: 'S2' }, { catID: 1, segmentId: '3', segmentName: 'S3' }],
    segments = [{ id: '3', name: 'S3' }, { id: '4', name: 'S4' }, { id: '5', name: 'S5' }],
    result = add(catalogs, segments);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This seems to be working fine. Can you also explain the solution a bit?

Comment: Could you keep the code same way as my original snipet?

Comment: what do you mean, actually?

Comment: Like on top we define catalog = [..], and then function addSegment(){... return newArray; }

Comment: And at the end function calling addSegment ([...])

Comment: You wrapped everything around one const ...

Comment: it is just a cosmetic question. you are free to adjust up to your flavour.

Comment: Yeah I was sorting it out but some peice  of code: Array.from(m.values())) was crashing. So is it possible for you to modify or add another section as second solution in your answer?

Comment: what part is crashing?

Comment: Array.from(m.values())) this part

Comment: @NinaScholz What if I want to merge segmentId and segmentName in nested json object in output resonse. like this: { catID: 2, segment: {segmentId: '2', segmentName: 'S2'} }

Comment: then you need to address the right property with a [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors).

Comment: @NinaScholz ... The grouping might to be done by both of an `catalogs` item's keys, `catID` and `segmentId`. Otherwise one later does create new invalid items with duplicates of the same `catID` and `segmentId` value combination, though the `segmentIDName` would be different. One easily can countercheck this with running a more complex test with e.g. `const segments = [{ id: '3', name: 'S3' }, { id: '2', name: 'S3' }, { id: '1', name: 'S3' }];` instead of the OP's single `segments` item. I started checking back with the OP.

Comment: @PeterSeliger, yes, it could be a problem. existing items stays, actually.

Comment: @StormTrooper ... Thus what the OP originally describes still counts ... _"[...] against each `catId` there could be multiple `segmentId`s **but `segmentId`s can not be duplicated for that specific `catId`**"_ ... which means the uniqueness of a `catalogs` item is defined by both of its key-values `catId` and `segmentId` regardless of an item's source or target data-format. And such items can not be duplicated and/or overwritten by then invalid combinations with `segments` items.  Thanks for the clarification, so far there are no questions left from my side.

Comment: Please have a look at my question edits, i just expanded my use case in order to get more clarification

Comment: @StormTrooper, it gives you the wanted result.

Comment: As I mentioned the nested Array.values() gives exception in my real ts environment

Comment: @StormTrooper, [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) is a standard method in javascript. maybe you need to address the returned type in advance for typescript. i havbe no idea from typescript and this question is not typed as typescript nor it has code in typescript. anyway the other answers does not have code in typescript, so for me, you could leave this question without and ask a new question regarding typescript definitions.

Comment: @NinaScholz ... final solution received a +1 in order to challenge the ranking of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

***Personal statement***

*"I will never really understand the attitude or state of mind of people who vote on answers in either direction without having dug themself deep into the matter. Thus said, I really would like to know the reason this answer got considered not useful even though its approach already with the first implementation did solve the OP's problem, which with the last edit has been proven once again, whereas another answer which right from the beginning until the time of voting never met the requirements already received two helpful votes.*

*I'm aware that people might feel offended by my writing and comments. And it tells more about the people itself. The style to those people might appear hard, even unfriendly; but couldn't it be that being precise and persistent just does make it sound like that? **Read my words always with a warm voice which is full of compassion towards helpfulness**."*

***Edit/Note** - Since the OP changed the requirements for the final data format, a small code refactoring got added to the originally provided solution.*

**Originally provides approach / solution – `2022-12-09`**

The beneath provided solution implements an approach which uses preprocessed lookup data ...

- the `catIDs` [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for existing catalog-IDs
- and the `catSegments` object for existing combinations of catalog- and segment-IDs.

The intermediate result, an array of newly created and valid catalog items, then gets computed by iterating over an array of existing `catID`s via [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) where for each `catID` one tries to create an array of new catalog items by [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)ing the passed `segments` array. The validity of each possible catalog item is assured by looking up whether it already exists as a combination of the same `catID` and `segmentId` values.

```js
function getUpdatedCatalogsWithSegmentsAggregation(
  catalogs = [], segments = []
) {
  // create lookup data,
  // - the `catIDs` set for existing catalog-IDs 
  // - and the `catSegments` object for existing
  //   combinations of catalog- and segment-IDs.
  const {

    catIDs,
    catSegments,

  } = catalogs

    .reduce((
      { catIDs, catSegments },
      { catID, segmentId, segmentName }
    ) => {
      catIDs.add(catID);
      catSegments[`${ catID }_${ segmentId }`] ??= segmentName;

      return { catIDs, catSegments };
    }, {
      catIDs: new Set,
      catSegments: {},
    });

  // try to create new/valid catalog items for each existing `catId`.
  const newCatalogs = [...catIDs]

    .flatMap(catID =>
      segments
        .reduce((list, { id: segmentId, name: segmentName }) => {

          const itemKey = `${ catID }_${ segmentId }`;
          if (!catSegments.hasOwnProperty(itemKey)) {

            // update lookup.
            catSegments[itemKey] = segmentName;

            // push new/valid catalog item into the aggregating list.
            list.push({ catID, segmentId, segmentName });
          }
          return list;

        }, [])
    );

  // - return a new array of ...
  //   ... originally passed ...
  return catalogs
    // ... and newly computed data.
    .concat(newCatalogs);
}


// The OP's original use case.
const catalogs = [
  { catID: 2, segmentId: '2', segmentName: 'S2' },
  { catID: 1, segmentId: '1', segmentName: 'S1' },
  { catID: 1, segmentId: '2', segmentName: 'S2' },
];
const segments = [{ id: '3', name: 'S3' }];

console.log(
  "The expected result of the OP's original use case ...",
  getUpdatedCatalogsWithSegmentsAggregation(catalogs, segments),
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

**Additional changes provided to the above original solution – `2022-12-11`**

The adapted example code leaves the above original implementation as is, but introduces an additional [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)ping  task which creates for each catalog item of the former result array a new item according to the OP's data structure changes. Thus the mapping function accepts a catalog item of the OP's base form and creates a new labeled catalog item.

This also proves the robustness of the first provided approach.

```js
function getUpdatedCatalogsWithSegmentsAggregation(
  catalogs = [], segments = []
) {
  const { catIDs, catSegments } = catalogs
    .reduce((
      { catIDs, catSegments },
      { catID, segmentId, segmentName }
    ) => {
      catIDs.add(catID);
      catSegments[`${ catID }_${ segmentId }`] ??= segmentName;

      return { catIDs, catSegments };

    }, { catIDs: new Set, catSegments: {} });

  const newCatalogs = [...catIDs]
    .flatMap(catID => segments
      .reduce((list, { id: segmentId, name: segmentName }) => {

        const itemKey = `${ catID }_${ segmentId }`;
        if (!catSegments.hasOwnProperty(itemKey)) {

          catSegments[itemKey] = segmentName;
          list.push({ catID, segmentId, segmentName });
        }
        return list;

      }, [])
    );

  return catalogs.concat(newCatalogs);
}

function createLabeledCatalogItemFromCatalogBase({ segmentName, ...data }) {
  return {
    // destructuring into `segmentName` and the `data` rest which is more
    // tolerant to further changes to the original/source data structure.
    ...data,
    label: {
      segmentIDName: `${ data.segmentId }_${ segmentName }`,
    },
  };
}


// The OP's latest provided use case.
const catalogs = [
  { catID: 3, segmentId: '3', segmentName: 'S3' },
  { catID: 2, segmentId: '2', segmentName: 'S2' },
  { catID: 2, segmentId: '3', segmentName: 'S3' },
  { catID: 1, segmentId: '1', segmentName: 'S1' },
  { catID: 1, segmentId: '2', segmentName: 'S2' },
  { catID: 1, segmentId: '3', segmentName: 'S3' },
];
const segments = [
  { id: '3', name: 'S3' },
  { id: '4', name: 'S4' },
  { id: '5', name: 'S5' },
];
console.log(
  "The expected result of the OP's latest provided use case ...",
  getUpdatedCatalogsWithSegmentsAggregation(catalogs, segments)
    .map(createLabeledCatalogItemFromCatalogBase)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Since you wrote your personal statement, I have come back to this and looked at the question again, adding a brand-new answer.  I had not previously voted up or down any answers, but I have now upvoted yours and Nina's.  But you should note that I am in general more likely to upvote ones from Nina, whose style and thought processes seem better aligned with my own than yours. A quick glance will often tell me if Nina's is correct, where I have to do more to check yours. So in scanning, I might upvote one and ignore the other. Someone else might have different criteria. Don't take it personally.

Comment: @ScottSauyet - Thanks for the words. It's kind of you though not needed since I do not take things personal here. I just sometimes do not understand upvoting of solutions which have neither been tested by the OP nor by the voting person. I too do not understand the opposite way where a lean/clean solution and/or a brilliant approach of others answers is obviously not comprehended as such since it would receive downvotes. And usually I'm not even effected. I mostly observe. But especially with how this thread went I had to step forward the first time sine I'm at SO in order to share my thoughts

Comment: @ScottSauyet - btw, regarding… _"But you should note that I am in general more likely to upvote ones from Nina, whose style and thought processes seem better aligned with my own than yours"_ …The approach of Nina's last/most current implementation is identical to mine and the one of your latest answer is too (upvoted as well). And it's not a surprise since everyone follows this one straightforward idea of how to solve the OP's problem most efficiently. And if it comes to code you and Nina sometimes prefer for and while loops whereas I'm always in favor of a reducing and mapping/filtering style

Comment: You'll find almost no `for` or `while` loops in my answers.  My comment is more on *style* than on *substance*. We all have our quirks.  Nina's single `const`/`let` statement bothers me. I know many people detest my quirky spacing conventions. I really don't like your `FullSenteceToDescribeAReducingFunctions` and its separation from the actual reduction. Those are not overly important, unless it happens to make the code more difficult for someone to read.  I think our answers are most often quite similar in content. But again, I'm more likely to upvote one I can see at a glance makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

My [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74745741/1243641) was based on a previous version of the question.  The current version of the question seems much changed (or perhaps I simply misread it.)  In any case, this seems to do what's required, fairly simply:

```js
const groupBy = (fn) => (xs, k) => 
  xs .reduce ((a, x) => ((k = fn (x)), (a [k] ??= []), (a [k] .push (x)), a), {})
  
const addSegs = (catalogs, newSegs) => newSegs .reduce (
  (data, {id, name}) => data .map (([cat, o]) => [cat, Object .assign (o, {[id]: name})]),
  Object .entries (
    groupBy (x => `_${x .catID}`) (catalogs)
  ) .map (([catID, group]) => [
      catID, 
      Object .assign (...group .map (({segmentId, segmentName}) => ({[segmentId]: segmentName})))
  ])
) .flatMap (([catID, segs]) => Object .entries (segs) .map (([segmentId, segmentName]) => ({
  catID: Number (catID .slice (1)), segmentId, segmentName 
}))) 
.map (({catID, segmentId, segmentName}) => ({catID, segmentId, label: { segmentIDName: `${segmentId}_${segmentName}`}}))


const catalogs = [{catID: 3, segmentId: '3', segmentName: 'S3'}, {catID: 2, segmentId: '2', segmentName: 'S2'}, {catID: 2, segmentId: '3', segmentName: 'S3'}, {catID: 1, segmentId: '1', segmentName: 'S1'}, {catID: 1, segmentId: '2', segmentName: 'S2'}, {catID: 1, segmentId: '3', segmentName: 'S3'}]
const newSegs = [{id: '3', name: 'S3'}, {id: '4', name: 'S4'}, {id: '5', name: 'S5'}]

console .log (addSegs (catalogs, newSegs))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

I think it would be much more logical with the last line commented out, in which case it gives an output more like this, without the `label` field and its merged data property:

```js
[
  {"catID": 3, "segmentId": "3", "segmentName": "S3"},
  {"catID": 3, "segmentId": "4", "segmentName": "S4"},
  {"catID": 3, "segmentId": "5", "segmentName": "S5"},
  {"catID": 2, "segmentId": "2", "segmentName": "S2"},
  {"catID": 2, "segmentId": "3", "segmentName": "S3"},
  {"catID": 2, "segmentId": "4", "segmentName": "S4"},
  {"catID": 2, "segmentId": "5", "segmentName": "S5"},
  {"catID": 1, "segmentId": "1", "segmentName": "S1"},
  {"catID": 1, "segmentId": "2", "segmentName": "S2"},
  {"catID": 1, "segmentId": "3", "segmentName": "S3"},
  {"catID": 1, "segmentId": "4", "segmentName": "S4"},
  {"catID": 1, "segmentId": "5", "segmentName": "S5"}
]
```

In either case, the logic is similar to many others here, first using a pretty standard utility function, `groupBy` to convert `catalogs` into:

```
{
  _3: [
    {catID: 3, segmentId: "3", segmentName: "S3"}
  ],
  _2: [
    {catID: 2, segmentId: "2", segmentName: "S2"}, 
    {catID: 2, segmentId: "3", segmentName: "S3"}
  ],
  _1:[
    {catID: 1, segmentId: "1", segmentName: "S1"}, 
    {catID: 1, segmentId: "2", segmentName: "S2"}, 
    {catID: 1, segmentId: "3", segmentName: "S3"}
  ]
}
```

and then using `Object .entries` to to this into an array of key-value pairs, where the keys look like `_3` and the values are arrays of `{catID, segmentId, segmentName}` objects.  (The leading underscores are added to avoid numeric-sorting of keys when we iterate the Object.  We remove them at the end.)

Then with `.map`, we turn these into this simpler format:

```js
[
    [_3, {3: "S3"}],
    [_2, {2: "S2", 3: "S3"}],
    [_1, {1: "S1", 2: "S2", 3: "S3"}]
]
```

With `newSegs .reduce`, we add our new segments to each, yielding this:

```js
[
    [_3, {3: "S3", 4: "S4", 5: "S5"}],
    [_2, {2: "S2", 3: "S3", 4: "S4", 5: "S5"}],
    [_1, {1: "S1", 2: "S2", 3: "S3", 4: "S4", 5: "S5"}]
]
```

With the `.flatMap` call, we rehydrate the properties, flattening our structure, and incidentally removing the `_`'s we used for sorting, yielding my preferred structure above.

Finally, we `.map` the results into new objects with your `{label}` sub-object.

If that really is the format you want, then I would suggest replacing the `.flatmap` and `.map` calls with this:

```js
.flatMap (([catID, segs]) => Object .entries (segs) .map (([segmentId, segmentName]) => ({
  catID: Number (catID .slice (1)), segmentId, label: { segmentIDName: `${segmentId}_${segmentName}`}
})))
```

which will do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Before getting to the answer: Your input data suggests that the pattern of the input segment name string is a capital letter `S` followed by an integer sequence. If that's the case, a `number` type would better represent the `segmentId` value of each object in the output array for your dataset... a `number` can be stringified using built-in methods with a 100% success rate — meaning that you can easily do that on demand later if you ever need the value as a string, but the reverse is not true: most strings cannot be parsed as numbers.

In context of the above, you can use a transform function to parse each input item into the desired output structure (and validate the values along the way). See the example code below:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#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-v66E15rAGYxDfC8r3Ec1v0fP9wOAlgP2vcCHw3Z9X3fUCxAQn8nzEACgNQz9AMQ39n0A4CAF11n6Kl1DQBAYGXWcBFPUiD1RVgmhPURDneOEBDAcwTECa5bnuRVDwgDAQAQOEQAwLwTA5X4UEJaAAHoACpoAAGVkiArEYc9YIzaAACIGUGYybBvYsWGM91zMs6yTPdRsLJMl9jNiGCASM0zU1cqyfLsyhXP-RzbPrQshFc4yAI8lgvOTEyzOCmxzTCoLXLSwKIt3BBoprc04pLd8fOSzL0py+zoACvMnJylybBim8ioS0q-NSiqdyq0Lsp3Bq3P-FqStq3yFhCzrsxS6AepG5zdnywbPMYUjGDUlSgA)

```ts
class AssertionError extends Error {
  override name = 'AssertionError';
}

function assert (expr: unknown, msg?: string): asserts expr {
  if (!expr) throw new AssertionError(msg);
}

type OutputItem = {
  catId: number;
  segmentId: number;
  segmentName: string;
};

function transform (item: InputItem): OutputItem {
  const segmentName = item.name;

  const catId = Number(item.id);
  assert(Number.isInteger(catId), `Couldn't parse category ID as integer`);

  const segmentId = Number(segmentName.slice(1));
  assert(Number.isInteger(segmentId), `Couldn't parse segment ID as integer`);

  return {
    catId,
    segmentId,
    segmentName,
  };
}

type InputSegmentName = `S${number}`;
type InputId = `${number}`;
type InputItem = { id: InputId; name: InputSegmentName; };

const input = [
  {id: '2', name: 'S2'},
  {id: '2', name: 'S3'},
  {id: '1', name: 'S1'},
  {id: '1', name: 'S2'},
  {id: '1', name: 'S3'},
  {id: '3', name: 'S3'},
] satisfies InputItem[];

const output = input.map(transform);
console.log(output); /* Logs:
[
  {
    "catId": 2,
    "segmentId": 2,
    "segmentName": "S2"
  },
  {
    "catId": 2,
    "segmentId": 3,
    "segmentName": "S3"
  },
  {
    "catId": 1,
    "segmentId": 1,
    "segmentName": "S1"
  },
  {
    "catId": 1,
    "segmentId": 2,
    "segmentName": "S2"
  },
  {
    "catId": 1,
    "segmentId": 3,
    "segmentName": "S3"
  },
  {
    "catId": 3,
    "segmentId": 3,
    "segmentName": "S3"
  }
]
*/
```

Compiled JS from the TS Playground:

```js
"use strict";
class AssertionError extends Error {
    constructor() {
        super(...arguments);
        this.name = 'AssertionError';
    }
}
function assert(expr, msg) {
    if (!expr)
        throw new AssertionError(msg);
}
function transform(item) {
    const segmentName = item.name;
    const catId = Number(item.id);
    assert(Number.isInteger(catId), `Couldn't parse category ID as integer`);
    const segmentId = Number(segmentName.slice(1));
    assert(Number.isInteger(segmentId), `Couldn't parse segment ID as integer`);
    return {
        catId,
        segmentId,
        segmentName,
    };
}
const input = [
    { id: '2', name: 'S2' },
    { id: '2', name: 'S3' },
    { id: '1', name: 'S1' },
    { id: '1', name: 'S2' },
    { id: '1', name: 'S3' },
    { id: '3', name: 'S3' },
];
const output = input.map(transform);
console.log(output); /* Logs:
[
  {
    "catId": 2,
    "segmentId": 2,
    "segmentName": "S2"
  },
  {
    "catId": 2,
    "segmentId": 3,
    "segmentName": "S3"
  },
  {
    "catId": 1,
    "segmentId": 1,
    "segmentName": "S1"
  },
  {
    "catId": 1,
    "segmentId": 2,
    "segmentName": "S2"
  },
  {
    "catId": 1,
    "segmentId": 3,
    "segmentName": "S3"
  },
  {
    "catId": 3,
    "segmentId": 3,
    "segmentName": "S3"
  }
]
*/
```

---

Update in response to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74735388/javascript-add-new-record-to-each-category-only-once/74735605?noredirect=1#comment131901946_74735605): If your actual dataset is different (e.g. segment names aren't all in the format you showed in your question) such that the above observation doesn't apply, then — of course — you don't have to parse the segment identifier as a number:

[Full code in the TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/MYGwhgzhAECCUFMBOAXAlgewHYFElIyWgQA8UEsATGPAogbwChpoMA3ZJNShaLMALa8AvNADk8CMnTZahMQG5GAX0aMAZgFcswGVmiQpqaAApSAByQAuaNoDWWDAHcsAGmgCIAcwD8NiChcWF4AlDaG0jAWDMzQaOqmAITRIdAoABYETnwI2ZLSmLj4hCaeoUqqjCgAnua8APKaKOZNAJLkAtCiTCzAYCitlDZYmgIARshKLFJeQlgDQ9ABQV5TSwizFCgAcoII-oFowRVKGtq6hWlIYFgQ6oSdJmgdNq1YLQMdYdCNzW0d0B60GA2AC602812Qi6cQ6ADp+EJTr1QShgf1BjDtqMJkgnvDuCE1hFUCZseNkHC0BA3uQvMgTH0FiF3AADADCGE0IEoWDEaPMYCQUnRdMI1WgrQAIgYYEc6chWUS1CjbmiZnMFjCNVsoQg4RAQGhgAgTABGZWxJAIFCaJD6IG9DGUVyxaYbTWDV0sd0QnZ7b3QZQVNQ1OqS95NADKHt1exhrKjABJ6Msjl5lKylGHeG8PpjRKyUyMKUhM9narnI58EJ1unFFnm2pQFHw9q9qzG-XrW8G1CC1XFqzCANqxejcGxiABMYnciP24ijs+UgYnixnc7bQinUYAzGJV+PJ+IzVuF7uz0eWOup2f5+2lyu1yexPft4uxPvDy+NweHzuS4HkeAC6Sz9NS6hoAgMBNjWAgjiBpwDmCXJ-GiohHB8cICGA5gmIENx3A8yooRgID6iAGBeCYaEfES0AAPQAFTQAAMtREBWIwY43m60AAERMoMAk2NOgYsAJOrzCJNgCdOAkSYJ0n+kIomCcuAmxNegL8UJzrqeJekqbJgl7opxmxpCezqQJ+5aSwOmOoJwmUOpZpKVJVkLLZZoWT6yneXqtlRn52lrnprnuZ5JluXJCkxUFNlyZp4XjpFBk2B5ll+qZAnmYl3bJRp5lpXxAX6T5Nh7oVnpxWZ-k+l5RVqSlpWOYwIGMMxjFAA)

```ts
type OutputItem = {
  catId: number;
  segmentId: string;
  segmentName: string;
};

function transform (item: InputItem): OutputItem {
  const segmentName = item.name;

  const catId = Number(item.id);
  assert(Number.isInteger(catId), `Couldn't parse category ID as integer`);

  const segmentId = segmentName.slice(1);

  return {
    catId,
    segmentId,
    segmentName,
  };
}
```

Compiled JS from the TS Playground:

```js
"use strict";
class AssertionError extends Error {
    constructor() {
        super(...arguments);
        this.name = 'AssertionError';
    }
}
function assert(expr, msg) {
    if (!expr)
        throw new AssertionError(msg);
}
function transform(item) {
    const segmentName = item.name;
    const catId = Number(item.id);
    assert(Number.isInteger(catId), `Couldn't parse category ID as integer`);
    const segmentId = segmentName.slice(1);
    return {
        catId,
        segmentId,
        segmentName,
    };
}
const input = [
    { id: '2', name: 'S2' },
    { id: '2', name: 'S3' },
    { id: '1', name: 'S1' },
    { id: '1', name: 'S2' },
    { id: '1', name: 'S3' },
    { id: '3', name: 'S3' },
];
const output = input.map(transform);
console.log(output); /* Logs:
[
  {
    "catId": 2,
    "segmentId": "2",
    "segmentName": "S2"
  },
  {
    "catId": 2,
    "segmentId": "3",
    "segmentName": "S3"
  },
  {
    "catId": 1,
    "segmentId": "1",
    "segmentName": "S1"
  },
  {
    "catId": 1,
    "segmentId": "2",
    "segmentName": "S2"
  },
  {
    "catId": 1,
    "segmentId": "3",
    "segmentName": "S3"
  },
  {
    "catId": 3,
    "segmentId": "3",
    "segmentName": "S3"
  }
]
*/
```

Comment: Actually i have unique identifiers as a primary key so it is based on a unique string something like this: "ATG556-HRY641-HRODJ"

Comment: i dont need to check for integer or string types here, could I get more simplified solution here. For me it is important to have a short precise and optimized solution

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74735388/javascript-add-new-record-to-each-category-only-once/74735605?noredirect=1#comment131901946_74735605) @StormTrooper I updated my answer in response to your comment.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const catalogs = [{
    catID: 2,
    segmentId: '2',
    segmentName: 'S2'
  },
  {
    catID: 1,
    segmentId: '1',
    segmentName: 'S1'
  },
  {
    catID: 1,
    segmentId: '2',
    segmentName: 'S2'
  }
];

function addSegmentsToCatalogs(segments) {

    const copyOfCatlogs = [...catalogs];

  const catlogIds = catalogs.map(c => c.catID);
  const uniqCatIds = [...new Set(catlogIds)];
  const segIds = segments.map(s => s.id);
  

  uniqCatIds.forEach(catId => {

    segIds.forEach(segId => {
      const hasCatIdWithSegment = copyOfCatlogs.findIndex(c => c.catID == catId && segId == c.segmentId);
      if (hasCatIdWithSegment == -1) {
        const newSegment = segments.find(s => s.id == segId);
        copyOfCatlogs.push({
          catID: catId,
          segmentId: newSegment.id,
          segmentName: newSegment.name,
        });
      }
    })
  })
  
  console.log(copyOfCatlogs);

  return copyOfCatlogs;
}

addSegmentsToCatalogs([{
  id: '3',
  name: 'S3'
}])
```

Comment: In your solution I think there is too much processing. i would like to go for an optimized solution here.

Comment: Yes, there are better ways, I just tried to make it logically more understandable with same concept in your code :)

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: See [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74856196/1243641) instead.

<del>We can do this fairly simply with the addition of a `groupBy` utility function, as found in many libraries.  Here's one version:</del>

```js
const groupBy = (fn) => (xs, k) => 
  xs .reduce ((a, x) => ((k = fn (x)), (a [k] ??= []), (a [k] .push (x)), a), {})

const addSegs = (catalogs, newSegs) => 
  Object .entries (groupBy (x => x .catID) (catalogs)) .flatMap (([catID, records]) =>
    records .concat (newSegs .map (({id, name}) => ({
      catID: Number (catID),
      segmentId: id,
      segmentName: name
    })))
  )

const catalogs = [{catID: 2, segmentId: '2', segmentName: 'S2'}, {catID: 1, segmentId: '1', segmentName: 'S1'}, {catID: 1, segmentId: '2', segmentName: 'S2'}]
const newSegs = [{id: '3', name: 'S3'}]

console .log (addSegs (catalogs, newSegs))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

<del>We first use `groupBy` to separate our input into groups based on a shared `catID`, yielding something like this:</del>

```
{
    "1": [
        {catID: 1, segmentId: "1", segmentName: "S1"},
        {catID: 1, segmentId: "2", segmentName: "S2"}
    ],
    "2": [
        {catID: 2, segmentId: "2", segmentName: "S2"}
    ]
}
```

<del>Calling `Object .entries` on that give us something like this:</del>

```
[
  ["1", [{"catID": 1, "segmentId": "1", "segmentName": "S1"}, {"catID": 1, "segmentId": "2", "segmentName": "S2"}]], 
  ["2", [{"catID": 2, "segmentId": "2", "segmentName": "S2"}]]
]
```

<del>Now we transform each of these and flatten the results by calling `flatMap`, passing it a function which maps over the new segments, creating objects that match our main records, appending them to the records and returning the whole set.  The only slightly odd thing is that we have to convert `catID` by wrapping it in `Number`.  We need that because when we created an object with numeric keys in `groupBy`, they are converted to strings behind the scenes.  We could use a `Map` instead, avoiding this problem, but adding slightly more complex syntax.</del>

<del>We could easily inline that `groupBy` function into our main one, but this is a widely reusable function; I would suggest keeping some such in a utility library, if you're not already using something like Ramda, lodash, or Underscore.</del>